# how to extract "any word" or sys.any from IBM Watson conversation?

Tags: api, bots, watson-conversation

I want to know if any possible way to detect System.any as an entity from IBM Watson Conversation, just to detect product name or some thing like that, i did it in some other APIs like API.ai, Nuance Mix and WIT.ai

Answer (score 1):

Apologies, I don't fully understand your request:

If you want to detect a system entity, you only need it's name. Like:

```
if bot recognises:  @sys-number 
...
```

You need to make sure that the system entity is switched on in the entities screen.

There is no "product name" entity you can pull. If you want to set a product name, you can try setting a context variable on the `welcome` node.

If it is you want to access the users input, you can use `input.text` to capture it, and use `input.text.find()` or `input.text.matches()` to do a regex match.

More details here:

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-methods.html#methods-to-process-values

Comment: i am sorry for the Unconscious content,let me explain that, as example if user says "get info about meeting named soft_meeting" or "i want to know more info about board meeting"
if their possible way to detect "soft_meeting" and "board" as a meeting name
note that meeting name in this case is a normal name i cannot detect it with regex, it will be hard to handle this issue in coding

Comment: Can you update your answer with what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

the question is 3 years old, but as of today i think watson is still not able to do @sys.any kind of slot extraction. this is one of the few key reason for some usecases to prefer dialogflow CX or other bot blatforms, as most other features are very similar.